# Unable to connect to OpenFire on EC2 from C#

Tags: c#, azure, amazon-ec2, openfire

I've a EC2 Micro Instance running OpenFire XMPP Server. I am trying to connect my c# + ASP.NET app to the server using `Jabber-net` library from my local machine. Unfortunately, I am getting an error saying "`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ***.***.***.***:5222`". I doubt this is a problem with the PORT but I am not able figure it out. This application is a Azure Cloud App, so is it possible to connect from Azure Cloud App to EC2 on port 5222?

I am using the below code;

```
JabberClient JClient = new JabberClient();   JID jid = new JID("user1", "im.domain.com", "");
JClient.User = "user1";
JClient.Password = "admin";
JClient.AutoLogin = false;
JClient.SSL = false;
JClient.OnError += JClient_OnError;
JClient.OnConnect += JClient_OnConnect;
JClient.OnLoginRequired += JClient_OnLoginRequired;
JClient.OnRegisterInfo += JClient_OnRegisterInfo;
JClient.OnRegistered += JClient_OnRegistered;
JClient.OnMessage += JClient_OnMessage;
JClient.Connect();
JClient.Register(jid);
JClient.Close(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you access your Xmpp server from an external xmpp client (e.g. Gajim)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I still don't know the reason but following are the changes that I've made;

- Created an A record to point the EC2 Instance
- Added SRV Records for Jabber Service
- Changed Library to agsXMPP